# How to make Windows 7 boot up each weekday morning?

Tags: windows-7, boot

On my Macs this is a simple built-in scheduling function.  But on my Windows 7 box this doesn't even seem to be possible.

I'd like to boot up (from a complete shutdown, *not* sleep or hibernation) each weekday morning (so Monday through Friday) at 4am.  BIOS does not allow choosing specific days, it will boot every day regardless.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: You need to make sure your network card and power supply supports Wake on LAN and then have the facility to send it a magic packet.   https://www.howtogeek.com/70374/how-to-geek-explains-what-is-wake-on-lan-and-how-do-i-enable-it/

Comment: I don't want to wake, I want to boot up.  Otherwise, there are many easy solutions for this.

Comment: Wake on LAN boots the computer

Comment: Oh wow, ok that I did not know.  I've only ever used it to wake a computer from a sleep state.  I might be able to have another machine send it a wake packet.  It's not an ideal solution but might work... will investigate.

Comment: Nope doesn't work.  Does work from sleep, but not from a powered-down state.  Using WakeOnLan on Mac to send the magic packet.  Definitely does work but only from sleep.

Comment: Aha, turns out WoL wasn't enabled on my Nic.  Appears to be working now... thanks for the tip!  Feel free to make it an answer if you like and I'll accept it.

Comment: I did do this for you

Comment: WoL is not necessary anyway which device should send the Wol packets? Just use the scheduling mechanism e.g. via [WOSB](https://dennisbabkin.com/wosb/) and then use the hibernate instead of power off.

Comment: Hibernate is not acceptable.  Must be a complete shut down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure your network card and power supply supports Wake on LAN and then have the facility to send it a magic packet. Here is the support for that:

https://www.howtogeek.com/70374/how-to-geek-explains-what-is-wake-on-lan-and-how-do-i-enable-it/

Answer (score 0):

Press Start and in the search box type “Task Scheduler.” At top your list of choices will be the Task Scheduler.

Click the Action menu and then select Create Basic task.

Choose a name for the task (like AutoReboot), type it in the Name box and click Next.

Select Weekly (if you want a Weekly reboot) and click Next

Type the time you want to boot up the computer, set recurrence to your liking, and click Next.

Select Start a program and click Next.
Click Browse and navigate to %SystemRoot%\System32 (that’s going to be C:\Windows\System32 for most people).  Find the file named Shutdown (.exe) and click Open. Type /F /R in the Add arguments (optional) box and click Next.
[Ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLxs2.png)
Click Finish.
✌️

Comment: Thanks but my understanding and experience is that it is not possible to execute any task from the Task Scheduler when the computer is completely powered down.  Why would this be any different?  Note that I am not looking to shut down on a schedule, I want to boot UP on a schedule.